# SD card initialization on STM32

Tags: c, stm32, spi, hal

I try to read a file from SD Card using SPI and FatFS and I have a problem with ACMD41.
Previously, the CMD0 and CMD8 give me correct response and I assume that I have a new v2 type.
When I send ACMD41 first time I get 0x01 response for both CMD55 and CMD41, so I send it the next time and I don't receive on the CMD55 other response than 0xff in 16 CLK cycles, so the initialization ends up returning an error. I have tried to write my own files to initialize card and used ready library which I have found on the Internet. I also think that there's no problem with SD card because I have tried four of them.

Below is the code, maybe sb will be able to find the solution or give me some advice or link to proven source..

```
/*
 * sd_spi.c
 *
 *  Created on: 26.11.2017
 *      Author: jaras
 */

#include "sd_spi.h"
#include <string.h>

uint8_t SDSPI_SendCMD(SPI_HandleTypeDef *phandle, uint8_t cmd, uint32_t arg, uint8_t crc) {
    uint8_t buf[6];
    buf[0] = cmd | 0x40;
    buf[1] = (arg >> 24) & 0xff;
    buf[2] = (arg >> 16) & 0xff;
    buf[3] = (arg >> 8) & 0xff;
    buf[4] = arg & 0xff;
    buf[5] = crc;

    if(HAL_SPI_Transmit(phandle, buf, 6, 1000) != HAL_OK) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

uint8_t SDSPI_Response(SPI_HandleTypeDef *phandle, uint8_t *buf, uint16_t size) {
    uint8_t tx = 0xff;
    uint8_t rx = 0xff;
    uint8_t i = 0;

    while(rx == 0xff) {
        if(HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(phandle, &tx, &rx, 1, 1000) != HAL_OK) {
            return 1;
        }
        i++;
        if(i > 8) {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    *buf = rx;

    for(uint16_t k = 1; k < size; k++) {
        if(HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(phandle, &tx, &rx, 1, 1000) != HAL_OK) {
            return 1;
        }
        *(buf + k) = rx;
    }

    return 0;
}

uint8_t SDSPI_CMD(SPI_HandleTypeDef *phandle, uint8_t cmd, uint32_t arg, uint8_t crc,
                    uint8_t *response, uint8_t size) {

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SDSPI_CSPORT, SDSPI_CSPIN, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    uint8_t res = SDSPI_SendCMD(phandle, cmd, arg, crc);
    if(res > 0) {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SDSPI_CSPORT, SDSPI_CSPIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        return 1;
    }

    res = SDSPI_Response(phandle, response, size);
    if(res > 0) {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SDSPI_CSPORT, SDSPI_CSPIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        return 2;
    }

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SDSPI_CSPORT, SDSPI_CSPIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    uint8_t tx = 0xff;
    if(HAL_SPI_Transmit(phandle, &tx, 1, 1000) != HAL_OK) {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SDSPI_CSPORT, SDSPI_CSPIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        return 3;
    }

    return 0;
}

uint8_t SDSPI_ACMD(SPI_HandleTypeDef *phandle, uint8_t cmd, uint32_t arg, uint8_t crc,
                    uint8_t *response, uint8_t size) {
    uint8_t value0;

    uint8_t rx = 0;

    uint8_t res = SDSPI_CMD(phandle, 55, 0, 0x65, &rx, 1);
    value0=rx;
    if(res > 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if((rx & 0xf4) > 0) {
        return 2;
    }

    res = SDSPI_CMD(phandle, cmd, arg, crc, response, size);
    if(res > 0) {
        return 3;
    }

    return 0;
}

uint8_t SDSPI_Init(SPI_HandleTypeDef *phandle) {
    uint8_t value0;
    uint8_t value1;
    uint8_t value2;
    uint8_t value3;
    uint8_t value4;

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SDSPI_CSPORT, SDSPI_CSPIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_Delay(10);
    uint8_t buf[] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};
    if(HAL_SPI_Transmit(phandle, buf, 10, 1000) != HAL_OK) {
        return 1; //spi error
    }

    uint8_t res = SDSPI_CMD(phandle, 0, 0, 0x95, buf, 1);
    value0 = buf[0];
    if(res > 0) {
        return 1; //command error
    }
    if(buf[0] != 1) {
        return 2; //not initialized
    }

    uint8_t type = 0;
    uint8_t block = 0;

    res = SDSPI_CMD(phandle, 8, 0x01aa, 0x87, buf, 5);
    value0 = buf[0];
    value1 = buf[1];
    value2 = buf[2];
    value3 = buf[3];
    value4 = buf[4];
    if(res > 0) {
        type = 1;
    }
    if(buf[0] != 1) {
        type = 1;
    }
    if((buf[3] & 0x0f) != 1 || buf[4] != 0xaa) {
        return 3; //initialization error
    }

    uint8_t stat = 0;
    uint32_t tickstart = 0;

    if(type == 0) {
        stat = 1;
        tickstart = HAL_GetTick();
        while(stat > 0) {
            if((HAL_GetTick()-tickstart) >= 1000) {
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SDSPI_CSPORT, SDSPI_CSPIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
                return 4; //timeout
            }

            res = SDSPI_ACMD(phandle, 41, 0x40000000, 0x77, &stat, 1);
            if(res > 0) {
                return 5; //not supported
            }
        }

        res = SDSPI_CMD(phandle, 58, 0, 0x75, buf, 5);
        if(res > 0) {
            return 6; //not supported
        }
        if(buf[0] > 0) {
            return 7;
        }
        if((buf[1] & 0x04) > 0) {
            block = 1;
        }

    }
    if(type == 1) {
        stat = 1;
        tickstart = HAL_GetTick();
        while(stat > 0) {
            if((HAL_GetTick()-tickstart) >= 1000) {
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SDSPI_CSPORT, SDSPI_CSPIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
                stat = 0;
                type = 2;
            }

            res = SDSPI_ACMD(phandle, 41, 0, 0xff, &stat, 1);
            if(res > 0) {
                stat = 0;
                type = 2;
            }
        }
    }
    if(type == 2) {
        stat = 1;
        tickstart = HAL_GetTick();
        while(stat > 0) {
            if((HAL_GetTick()-tickstart) >= 1000) {
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SDSPI_CSPORT, SDSPI_CSPIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
                return 8; //timeout
            }

            res = SDSPI_CMD(phandle, 1, 0, 0xff, &stat, 1);
            if(res > 0) {
                return 9; //error
            }
        }
    }
    if(block == 0) {
        res = SDSPI_CMD(phandle, 16, 512, 0xff, buf, 1);
        if(res > 0) {
            return 10; //not supported
        }
        if(buf[0] > 0) {
            return 11; //error
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
  



/*
 * sd_spi.h
 *
 *  Created on: 26.11.2017
 *      Author: jaras
 */

#ifndef SD_SPI_H_
#define SD_SPI_H_

#include "stm32f3xx_hal.h"
#include "gpio.h"

#define SDSPI_CSPORT CS_PIN_GPIO_Port
#define SDSPI_CSPIN CS_PIN_Pin

uint8_t SDSPI_Init(SPI_HandleTypeDef *phandle);
uint8_t SDSPI_ReadInfo(SPI_HandleTypeDef *phandle, uint16_t *sector, uint32_t *capacity);
uint8_t SDSPI_ReadBlock(SPI_HandleTypeDef *phandle, uint32_t lba, uint8_t *buf, uint16_t size);
uint8_t SDSPI_WriteBlock(SPI_HandleTypeDef *phandle, uint32_t lba, uint8_t *buf, uint16_t size);


#endif /* SD_SPI_H_ */
```

Comment: Chances of someone going over your library and debug it are rather low. But if such a person is found, they will need to run it, so there should be a `main` included that demonstrates your problem. Generally ... pay attention to command sequences and timings (delays and speeds). I assume HW is probably OK, since some commands work, but maybe not. Can you check you see what's expected on an oscilloscope?

Comment: To run, you just need to configure SPI and CD pins, next run SDSPI_Init in main. I have added header file with these pins and the code is complete right now. Unfortunately I don't have an oscilloscope

Comment: You're making many assumptions about what's working right and where the problem is. If this is some existing library, chances are the problem is in your code - library usage, HW configuration (clocks, GPIOs etc) or the HW itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at SD Card, it hasn"t initialized both on SPI and SDIO witg ready FatFS library and SDIO files generated by CubeMX. I've bought a new card and now it works fine on SDIO. I haven"t checked it on SPI yet, but I suspect there is problem with formatting